# How to call a filename into an excel formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently creating an Excel file that's purpose is to create a version compare between two Excel files. Since the file being compared has up to 30 sheets at any given time, and we will want to perform this daily, I wanted to create a macro to generate the file automatically.

The macro was designed to create a tab in the comparison file and paste a formula in a specified range. The formula is a nested IF statement:

1. If the cell contains a text value, return the text value, else:
2. If the cell is blank, return a blank value, else:
3. Calculate the difference between the current version and the prior version

The formula uses the INDIRECT function so that I can use the formula for all worksheets without having to specifically create one for each worksheet in the files.

The issue I'm currently having is layering in the two file names into the Excel formula. I created two dimensions with the filenames, however I don't believe I structured it correctly as I'm getting #NAME? errors from the formula created. Below is some of the code I'm using:

```
If SH.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then

    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:= _
             ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
    WS.Name = SH.Name

    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(ISTEXT(INDIRECT(""'[""&FileNameCurrent&""]""&ThisSheetName()&""'!""&CELL(""address"",RC))),INDIRECT(""'[""&FileNameCurrent&""]""&ThisSheetName()&""'!""&CELL(""address"",RC)),IF(INDIRECT(""'[""&FileNameCurrent&""]""&ThisSheetName()&""'!""&CELL(""address"",RC))="""","""",INDIRECT(""'[""&FileNameCurrent&""]""&ThisSheetName()&""'!""&CELL(""address"",RC))-INDIRECT(""'[""&FileNamePrior&""]""&ThisSheetName()&""'!""&CELL(""address"",RC))))"
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A1:Y100").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Calculate


End If
```

Comment: You haven't included an example of the formula causing the error.  I suspect it's because `FileNameCurrent` and `SheetNameCurrent` are not Excel functions.  I assume they are variables that you've populated elsewhere but you haven't bothered sharing that either.  If they are, then they should not be encapsulated in quotes because they must be evaluated before the formula is created.

Comment: Apologies, should have included the full code but didn't want to overwhelm. You were correct those were variables defined elsewhere in the code, based on Tom's answer below looks like I just had some missplaced quotes. Appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `SheetNameCurrent`, `FileNameCurrent` and `FileNamePrior` are all `VBA` variables/functions use the following. I think you had a few misplaced quote marks

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISTEXT(INDIRECT(""'[" & FileNameCurrent & "]" & ThisSheetName & "'!"" & cell(""address"", RC))), INDIRECT(""'[" & FileNameCurrent & "]" & ThisSheetName & "'!"" & cell(""address"", RC)), IF(INDIRECT(""'[" & FileNameCurrent & "]" & ThisSheetName & "'!"" & CELL(""address"",RC))="""","""",INDIRECT(""'[" & FileNameCurrent & "]" & ThisSheetName & "'!"" & CELL(""address"", RC))-INDIRECT(""'[" & FileNamePrior & "]" & ThisSheetName & "'!"" & CELL(""address"", RC))))"
```

Comment: This solved my issue - thank you for your help Tom!